# header() redirects page automatically instead of after submission of form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email

I created a form that will mail automatically when submit is clicked. After the mail is sent, i want to direct the user to a thank you page. i researched and came across the `header()` function for `php` and tried it with the code below.

```
<?php

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $party = $_POST['party'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Party Size: $party \n Message: $message";
        $recipient = "me@gmail.com";
        $subject = "New Private Party Submission";
        $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";


        if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)) {

            header("Location: https://example.com/thank-you");

        }


?>
```

What it does is automatically redirect me to the "thank you" page, obviously not what I want.

Here is the HTML for the form. i should mention the PHP is on the same page as the html

I should mention that mail function does work before I do this, i get emails send to that address when selected. However, it does not clear the fields.

I assumed that the if() would check if the mail function had executed properly, which it would if it had fields filled in, but this is obviously not the case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: *"obviously not what I want"* Not clear why not unless you are running this code within page that displays the form but that isn't what is shown. If the fields are empty it's up to you to validate them first. Really not clear what specific problem is

Comment: What else do you expect `mail()` to do? Calling it twice is also unlikely to accomplish much.  What fields should it clear?

Comment: Also doesn't make sense calling `mail()` twice

Comment: Okay I didn't actually use the mail() function twice, I was playing with it in different places and forgot to take this out before I posted here, it is edited now. As far as not clear what the specific problem is - I am trying to send the user to a new page after they click on "submit" but that doesn't happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a working example of a `PHP` file with a `form` that `submits to itself`, sends an `email`, and if the email was sent successfully then it redirects to `https://example.com/thank-you`.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
// Check if there is a valid $_POST request that is not empty
if ($_POST)
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $call= $_POST['callBack'];
    $party = $_POST['party'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $formcontent="From: ".$name."\nPhone: ".$phone."\nCall Back: ".$call."\nParty Size: ".$party."\nMessage: ".$message;
    $recipient = "me@gmail.com";
    $subject = "New Private Party Submission";
    $mailheader = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>';

    $mailResult = mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

    // better to store mail result in a variable
    if($mailResult)
    {
        header("Location: https://example.com/thank-you");
        exit();
        // use exit to terminate program and exit to header location
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr>
       <td><label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><label for="email">Email: </label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><label for="phone">Phone: </label><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><label for="callBack">Call back: </label><input type="text" id="callBack" name="callBack" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><label for="party">Party: </label><input type="text" id="party" name="party" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><label for="message">Message: </label><textarea  id="message" name="message" ></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="clickToEnter" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This still redirects immediately on loading the page. I think i need an `if()` function in the php at the top that is called when the submit button is clicked on the form.

Comment: @logos_164 OK, this PHP is on the same page as the form? I will edit to fix that

Comment: Yes it is, sorry i updated the question later to reflect this because someone in the comments mentioned that as well.

Comment: @logos_164 OK, try now. (i added the `if ($_POST){ }`)

Comment: @logos_164 I have fixed some typos in the code, and tested it to prove it works. I will update my answer to give a complete working example. Just copy my code into a new file to test it.

Comment: Woul this be different if you ran it on wordpress? That is what I'm running it in and what it does is it takes back to the domain, but what appears is the home page, even though the url is www.example.com/original-page

Comment: @logos_164 This should would fine in wordpress, just copy the PHP  code from my example and paste it somewhere in your wordpress file. If  something doesn't work, try echoing your variables (`$_POST['name'], ...`), there might be an error there. Like this `echo $_POST['name']; echo $_POST['email']; // etc.`.

Comment: @logos_164 The only thing you could have a problem with in wordpress is the `<form action=""`. Leaving the action empty should send the data to the same page. But if it doesn't work then try adding this `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` to the form action tag.

Comment: adding the $_SERVER was the magic word, good diagnosis, thank you!